# Excel: Parsing Addresses

Tags: excel, python-2.7, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have webscraped some data on restaurants in Thailand. I am currently having an issue with the address field because on the website when the address moved to the next line, the scrape decided to combine it and not leave any space. For example:

```
22/F, Dusit Thani Bangkok946 Rama 4 RoadBangkokThailand 
1/F, Oakwood Residence113 Thonglor Soi 13BangkokThailand 
G/F, Ocean Tower IISukhumvit Soi 21WattanaBangkokThailand
```

In the first entry I would want a space between the k and 9 and the d and the B, and so on so forth for the other entries.

I am currently using BeautifulSoup to scrape the data from [here](http://www.chope.co/bangkok-restaurants/list_of_restaurants). If anyone could help me out in a method to parse this or a better way to scrape the HTML I am all ears. I would prefer to not manually alter 280+ address entries.

Comment: The first part, separating a letter from a number, wouldn't be too tricky. The next issue is the separaing of "road" from "bangkok".  Is it *always* going to be "Bangkok"? Or, do you have a list of cities that we could use? I'm thinking to take each cell, and where there's a number next to a letter, add space in between.  Then, we'd just need to know what cities to add a space with, and country (assumedly only "Thailand", so not that big of an issue on that one).

Comment: Yea I had a feeling that was going to be the hard part. Unfortunately it puts other cities in there as well, like: Samutprakarn and etc. How would you go about separating the letter from the number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your examples show several patterns requiring space insertion:

- Small letter followed by a Capitalized letter
- Small letter followed by a digit
- digit followed by a Capitalized letter

  - (but this last may have a problem with an address that includes both digits and letters)

This can be done with Regular Expressions, developing a User Defined Function in VBA.

---

```
Option Explicit
Function SplitAddress(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object
    Const sPatNumberCap As String = "\d(?=[A-Z])"
    Const sPatNonCapNumberOrCap As String = "[a-z](?=[A-Z0-9])"
    Const sRepl As String = "$& "
    Dim sTemp As String

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")    
With RE
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = False

    .Pattern = sPatNumberCap
    sTemp = .Replace(S, sRepl)

    .Pattern = sPatNonCapNumberOrCap
    sTemp = .Replace(sTemp, sRepl)
End With

SplitAddress = sTemp

End Function
```

---

If the address 2A some street is a problem, you might be able to change .Pattern depending on what those types of strings really look like.  It might be enough to ensure that the space is only inserted if the is a non-white space character following the Capital letter.

eg:

```
Const sPatNumberCap As String = "\d(?=[A-Z]\S)"
```

but without examples, hard to speculate.

Comment: Wow thank you. That worked like a charm. I really need to brush up on my regex.